# How do I use bindToController with $compile

Tags: angularjs

I have the following simple code (in Coffeescript).

```
newScope = $rootScope.$new()
newScope.test = "test"
template = angular.element('<my-thing></my-thing>')
linkFn = $compile(template)
element = linkFn(newScope)
angular.element("#thingContainer").html('').append(element)
```

My thing uses the test variable as a scope and has the bindToController...

```
controller: MyThingController
controllerAs: 'mtc'
bindToController: true
$scope:  
  test: "="
```

And my controller looks like this

```
class MyThingController
  constructor: ($scope) ->
    console.log($scope.test)
    console.log(this.test)
```

Since I have the bindToController I would expect this.test to resolve properly and $scope.test to be undefined, however, it works the exact opposite.

So my question is how do I pass a $scope that still gets binded to the controller when using $compile?

Answer (score 0):

It needed to be in `$onInit` instead of constructor.